# How is RequestDispatcher implemented?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a RequestDispatcher, so I checked tomcat's source code, the ApplicationDispatcher class, but there are many places I can't understand.

I found in the ApplicationDispatcher class that the method used to forward request and response to the designated resource is the invoke(ServletRequest,ServletResponse) method, and this part is responsible for executing forward:

```
support.fireInstanceEvent(InstanceEvent.BEFORE_DISPATCH_EVENT, servlet, request, response);
// for includes/forwards   
if ((servlet != null) && (filterChain != null)) {
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
// Servlet Service Method is called by the FilterChain   
support.fireInstanceEvent(InstanceEvent.AFTER_DISPATCH_EVENT, servlet, request, response);
```

I can't understand this part of code, does this mean the RequestDispatcher.forward() and RequestDispatcher.include() methods are all executed in a filterchain? Can anyone tell me the   working machanism of tomcat's ApplicationRequestDispatcher?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to create your own implementation of `RequestDispatcher`?

Comment: I'm trying to make a jsp server by my own,I think it helps me to better understand java ee technology, so I have to implement the RequestDispatcher, lol

Comment: *(Seems you've bit off more than you can chew).* If you have filter, they are executed in order though the use of a filter chain. The end of the chain is the execution of the Servlet. There are 4 different filter chains: `REQUEST` applied to incoming requests, `FORWARD` applied when calling `forward()`, `INCLUDE` applied when calling `include()`, and `ERROR` applied when container needs to show an error page. Which means that in order to actually *do* a `forward()` or `include()` to a new Servlet, a new filter chain is started, culminating in the execution of the new Servlet.